# How to stretch this button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am learning flutter, and faced this issue:
I want the **equal button** to stretch to the left and cover the whole green area as shown in the picture.
The **equal button** is in one column and the other four buttons are in another column. And in turn, both of these columns are in a row. i.e

```
Column:
  Row:  
    Column 1:  
      Equal-Button // If I warp it in expended, it goes out of sight.
    Column 2:  
      the other four buttons
```

What is the proper way to fix it, not just hacks. How would you do it?
Here is the whole code:
[Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/mahanmarwat/415ef681389331de9ec39aa31daafba1)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have it in its own column then use **crossAxisAlignment.stretch**. Just ensure it occupies a finite space

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the Elevated Button with Sized Box and give it a width of your choice,
than if you want to put the '=' string to the right instead of center you can just wrap the text with align and set alignemnt to your choice

```
 SizedBox(
              width: 300,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey.shade600),
                ),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Text(
                    "=",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26),
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            )
```

Comment: So this is working and it is indeed stretching the button. But there is a problem with this approach, while different devices have different sizes, when I set 400 width instead of 300 it gives me render overflow.

Comment: When i said width to 300 it was just for an example, you can use width of your choice and maybe use Media Query to get the width of the screen.

Comment: Or just use flex widgets like Column and use crossAxisAlignment of your choice

Comment: I have updated my question -- added some missing info, if you could kindly check it now. I am using **Column** and tried all these different **crossAxis**, **mainAxis** properties but none is working for me. As for the media queries, I am aware of that but as of now I don't understand how to use them, also media queries seem like an overkill for such a small task.

Comment: here copy and paste this https://pastebin.com/ymVgWSsc, and make sure to read about Media Query

Comment: and if it works please give a ✓ to the answer

Comment: https://pastebin.com is down for me. Can you share it on any other platform? thanks,

Comment: https://justpaste.it/4zf6h

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both the `=` button and `/` button are in a `Row` widget you could wrap the `=` button in a `Expanded` widget forcing it to take all available space along it `MainAxis`.
Here's a quick example:

---

```
class Sample extends StatelessWidget {
  const Sample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 50)),
        Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 100,
          color: Colors.green,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The **equal button** is in its own column and when I warp it in **expended**, it goes out of sight.